# How to make something happen ONLY when clicking in an exact coordinate

Tags: javascript, canvas

I just wanted to know how I could make something on a canvas change clicking ONLY on a specific area of the canvas.

Let's say my canvas is of width 400px and height 400px, and I am drawing a face.
If I click on an eye, I want it to change. Let's say the eye is in the coordinates (drawn with .arc()) (135,70,15,0,Math.PI*2,true).

How can I make it so that when I click anywhere inside said eye, and nowhere else, something happens?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually compute if the mouse is in the eye. The best, simple and most precise solution would be to use [`ctx.isPointInPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath). This API will tell you if a point is in the current shape you are drawing. Example :

```
ctx.arc(135,70,15,0,Math.PI*2,true)

if(ctx.isPointInPath(your_mouse.x, your_mouse.y)) {
    doSomething()
}
```

Else you can do some hit-testing, but that's way more complicated depending on the shape of your object. Example for a rectangle :

```
if(
    mouse.x > rect.x && mouse.y > rect.y &&
    mouse.x < (rect.x + rect.width) && mouse.y < (rect.y + rect.height)
) {
    doSomething()
}
```

Comment: Much simpler than my answer - Didn't know about `ctx.isPointInPath` which looks neat.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement *[hit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit-testing)*.

- Keep track of your drawn objects in a Scene Graph - a kind of DOM that contains objects and their positions.
- When you click somewhere you need to compare the position of the click with the the positions of your objects.
- If the click [point lies within the area of a drawn object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon), you consider that a *hit*.

---

That or just ahead and use a canvas library that keeps such a Scene Graph for you, such as [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) or [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) - both libraries allow for [hit-testing](http://paperjs.org/examples/hit-testing/) as well.